# CAT6A or CAT7 Bulk Patch Cable

Tags: networking, ethernet

Is there a reason that no-one offers stranded CAT6A or CAT7 bulk cables to be used to crimp custom length patch cables? I haven't found a single supplier that offers this. Solid conductor cables are available for both mentioned categories but the highest category cable I can find with stranded cables are CAT6.

Is there an alternative when trying to accomplish 10Gbit compliance across greater distances than 55 meters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cat6A stranded cable is on sale in the USA and Europe. I know you can get it in the UK. Just Google "Cat6a stranded bulk".

Comment: Thank you for the link! Seems like there are few (if any) suppliers in Europe, so perhaps it's a regional issue. At least now I know it exists.